# Continuously deploying a Symfony app on Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, amazon-cloudformation, symfony

My current plan is to begin hosting my team's Symfony-based app on a load-balanced, autoscaling group generated via Cloudformation.

When someone on my team pushes to our Github repo, I would like AWS to automatically pull the latest codebase and install any new packages automatically, with no downtime. The database would not be part of the Cloudformation stack so that is not an issue.

How would I go about configuring my AWS infrastructure to accomplish this?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF. Your question is a little too broad. Please seek out relevant documentation and show what you have tried to implement yourself. Ask for more specific advice on points of difficulty.

Answer (score 0):

Actually CloudFormation works in the lines of creation / setup / reproducing the instance stack quickly.

However your requirement is about the latest code-base and releases. Try considering Puppet. Puppet is a configuration management tool, you can coming the power of continuous integration and puppet

> **What is Puppet?** - From the Puppet Website
>
> Puppet is a declarative, model-based approach to IT automation,
> helping you manage infrastructure throughout its lifecycle, from
> provisioning and configuration to orchestration and reporting. Using
> Puppet, you can easily automate repetitive tasks, quickly deploy
> critical applications, and proactively manage change, scaling from 10s
> of servers to 1000s, on-premise or in the cloud.

More information about Puppet

http://puppetlabs.com/puppet/what-is-puppet

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puppet_(software)

http://www.olindata.com/technology/puppet